# How to improve performance of a SQL JOIN with an OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, hana

**Complicated JOIN query as:**

```
SELECT 
  FIRST.NAME,
  SECOND.FIRST_NAME,
  SECOND.LAST_NAME
FROM FIRST_TABLE FIRST
LEFT JOIN SECOND_TABLE SECOND 
  ON (SECOND.FIRST_NAME = FIRST.NAME OR SECOND.LAST_NAME = FIRST.NAME)
```

Will result with bad performance.

***How to get better performance?***

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: I was just sharing some knowledge of an issue that I had to deal with. The main idea is that separating the join conditions and the use of cases is better than using a complicated join.

Comment: Have you tried to add index? Use sub query instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Are `SECOND.FIRST_NAME` and `SECOND.LAST_NAME` both unique within `SECOND`?

Comment: We can assume the columns are unique for that case.

Comment: Have you tried UNION?

Comment: Can we assume that `SECOND.FIRST_NAME` never equals `SECOND.LAST_NAME` for any record in `SECOND_TABLE`?

Comment: UNION will not help me here since I want to JOIN two tables together with a complicated JOIN query. The main issue is the performance.

Comment: Is this the real-life query, or an approximation? It doesn't seem that complex, but if you've got a really complex query you need help with, maybe you should post that one.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51914/slow-join-behaviour-with-or-in-predicate

Comment: It is a real life issue. It becomes complex when you JOIN those two tables while each contains 1 million rows. The difference from running a 500milis vs 5 secs is important.

Comment: Yikes! That's a big difference!

Comment: ... although, do you actually intend to retrieve 1 million rows, or some subset of the 1 million? I doubt you could read 1 million out of a database into an app in 5 seconds (though I don't know your app, of course!)

Comment: It's possible when you have a strong database but that not the issue. I don't count the difference by the time in seconds but the change by percentages.

Comment: You're absolutely right that having an `OR` in a join (or a `WHERE`) produces slow performance. @xQbert's link is on-point.  And there are a number of ways to get around it: which way is best depends on the indices, the number of records in the result set, the size of the data per row, and various other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You may be better off with `exists`:

```
SELECT FIRST.ID, FIRST.NAME
FROM FIRST_TABLE FIRST 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SECOND_TABLE SECOND WHERE SECOND.FIRST_NAME = FIRST.NAME) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SECOND_TABLE SECOND WHERE  SECOND.LAST_NAME = FIRST.NAME);
```

Then for performance, you want indexes on `SECOND_TABLE(LAST_NAME)` AND `SECOND_TABLE(FIRST_NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, see what you get. It would depend a lot on the indexes on `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`, but it avoids the `OR`.

```
SELECT 
  FIRST.NAME,
  SECOND.FIRST_NAME,
  SECOND.LAST_NAME
FROM FIRST_TABLE FIRST
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT S1.FIRST_NAME as TEST_NAME,
            S1.FIRST_NAME,
            S1.LAST_NAME       
     FROM   SECOND_TABLE S1
     WHERE  S1.FIRST_NAME <> S1.LAST_NAME
     UNION ALL
     SELECT S2.LAST_NAME as TEST_NAME,
            S2.FIRST_NAME,
            S2.LAST_NAME       
     FROM   SECOND_TABLE S2
   ) AS SECOND
  ON FIRST.NAME = SECOND.TEST_NAME
```